# Change the colour of citations in the Tufte book class

Tags: color, citing, tufte

How can I change the colour used for margin citations in the Tufte book class to grey? I'd like for the citations to take a visual back-seat to margin notes and figure/table descriptions.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific hook for that, but you could use the `\setcitationfont` command.  Something like `\setcitationfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\textcolor{gray}}` should work.

Comment: Can you also please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what you want, (ie with some sort of bibliography for the citations). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Thruston, thank you that did the trick. Though I found it had to be \setcitationfont{...\color{gray}}   instead of \textcolor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tufte-book` class does not provide a hook for the colour of footnotes, but it does provide one for the font, so you could try adding this to the preamble.

```
 \setcitationfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\color{gray}}
```

**NB**: Since there is no MWE for this question, I have not been able to test this!